# Upgrade Advice?

Tags: discussion

Is android.stackexchange.com the correct place to ask a question about whether I should upgrade or fix a broken nexus one? I nearly posted a question, but I'm not sure if this is the right place for that. What does the community think? My main worry is that it's fairly open ended and subjective. There's not really a "right" answer, however, the feedback given (especially if well justified) could be very helpful to me and others in a similar situation.

Comment: You could always drop into the Android chat room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question to ask is, can this be generalized to help others in the future, and if so, how much?

Otherwise it's basically a shopping question:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: I think I will avoid asking my question. It seems like the "answers" would be useful only to a very small subset of people and the answers would depend on the current state of the market (as in which phones are currently available to upgrade to) so it would have very limited applicability going forward..