# Question about upgrade experience for a specific device

Tags: discussion, scope

(Possibly related to [Upgrade Advice?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333/upgrade-advice); not really I reckon.)

**Is it appropriate here** to ask questions about how a particular Android device will look/behave and what features it will have added/removed in case I upgrade from Android X.X to Y.Y? Not looking for a complete list compiled for me, just specific features listed in the question.

My rationale: Because one can't, without rooting the device and doing other things, go back to the Android version one had before the upgrade, I'm not exactly jumping up and down to install the newest version available from the manufacturer. I lurk on youtube for videos that feature the upgraded phone, I read articles and reviews, but when I can't find answers to a particular worry, I would really appreciate advice from a person who has already upgraded that same device.

Comment: Are you referring solely to stock ROM updates?

Comment: I would say so. The ones that are available from the device manufacturer, not unsupported ones.

Comment: "What is your experience" type questions are usually best off in the chatroom, if you can find someone who has done what you're thinking of doing you can actually have a proper back-and-forth there.

Comment: Perfect example just posted: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28818/what-changed-from-cyanogenmod-9-0-to-9-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a question with a definite, non-subjective answer (as long as you just say what has changed and how, and stay away from saying if it's an actual improvement or now).

However it's also very localized in time. The answer is only ever going to be useful for someone with your make/model and firmware version. The number of people with that combination is going to shrink to none over time as people pick up and apply the update.

I think that this is probably something that would need to be taken on a question by question basis, and probably only for very major updates (eg 2.3 -> 4), or updates that would affect a lot of devices in the same way (eg a TouchWiz or Sense UI update).

Comment: Seems too localized to me, especially when talking about one particular device. I mean, they do publish the changelogs for each version.